# Como tirar a borda de um datagrid do primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Como faço para tirar a borda de um datagrid do primefaces???

segue a parte do código que utilizo o datagrid:

```
<p:dataGrid columns="3" value="#{projetistaBean.listaDeProjetistas}" var="projetista" styleClass="ui-datagrid"  >
```

e a parte do código que personalizo o datagrid:

```
.ui-datagrid{
    border: none;
}
```

e nada da borda sair

Answer (score 1):

Tente remover a borda do <kbd>ui-datagrid</kbd> e do <kbd>ui-datagrid-content</kbd>

```html
<style>
    .ui-datagrid{border: none !important;}  
    .ui-datagrid-content {border: none !important;}  
</style>
```

Comment: foi o que eu fiz. Mas não dá certo. Depois acrescentei: 
.ui-datagrid tr{
border: none !important;
}

Comment: o problema é que eu consigo tirar as bordas das linhas e das colunas do datagrid, mas do componente geral(a borda que envolve todo o datagrid) não sai

Comment: Tente desta outra forma... (vide alteração)

Answer (score 0):

Modificando a classe .ui-datagrid você acaba alterando para todos, mas se você quiser alterar apenas de um único específico faça assim:

```
<style>
    .noGridBorder tr, .noGridBorder td{border: none!important}
</style>

<p:panelGrid styleClass="noGridBorder">
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrível que eu nunca precisei fazer isso, mas  2 horas depois de ver esta questão surgiu a necessidade, :).

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

```
 <p:dataGrid ... styleClass="teste">
    ...
 </p:dataGrid>
```

No ficheiro com os estilos:

```
.teste .ui-widget-content
{
    border: none !important;
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Simples,

`.ui-panelgrid td, .ui-panelgrid tr{
    border: none !important;" 
}`